# Find the interior and boundary of $S$.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Consider the set $S=\{z^4-5i: 0<a<b\}$.
Here $z=a+ib$. Find the interior and boundary of $S$. Is $S$ closed?

I am kinda completely stuck on the following problem. I dont have any problem with understanding the problem. But I dont understand how to find its interior and boundary.

I tried expanding $z^4$ and writing out $z^4-5i$ in detail but I dont find that helping.

Is there any trick to attack these type of problems?
Can someone please help.

Comment: Tell us (by **editing the question**) what you already understand about the problem.  Have you tried approaching it via polar coordinates?

Comment: I don't understand the *definition* of your set $S$. You collect all points of the form $z^4 - 5i$ under some condition that refers to the real and imaginary parts? Write the set in a standard form. Are $a$ and $b$ pregiven and fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we can write z in polar representation:
$$z = \vert z \vert(\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)$$
Since $0 < a < b$ then $\cos\theta < sin\theta$. Next, notice that both the real part and the imaginary part of $z$ are positive, hence z must be in the 1 quadrant. Therefore, $\frac{\pi}{4} < \theta < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Then by DeMoivre's theorem:
$$z^4 = \vert z \vert^4(\cos 4\theta + i \sin 4\theta)$$
Since $\pi < 4\theta < 2\pi$, then the set $z^4$ would be the set of all complex numbers w, such that $Im(w) < 0$. From there subtracting $5i$ just shifts the set down by 5. This set will have a boundary at the horizontal line $y = -5$ and is not closed

Comment: Will it be open?

Comment: @Math_Freak Yes since $Im(w) < -5$, it has a "fuzzy" boundary.